# Move Rows From Multiple Tabs With a Historic Date in Column A to a Single Tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with multiple tabs all with a date in column A. 
I need a script that I can run using a trigger each night to move all rows with a historic date in Column A to a single tab for historic rows.

I have been successful in getting historic rows in my first sheet to move to the historic tab however I cannot seem to make the script work for multiple tabs.

```
function HistoricDates() {

SHEET_NAME = "Area1" || "Area2" || "Area3"||"Area4";

  // Initialising
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
  var PastSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historic Sheet");  
  var lastColumn = Sheet.getLastColumn();

  // Check all values from sheets
  for(var i = Sheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--){

   // Check if the value is a valid date

    var dateCell = Sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();  //Dates in column 1
    if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
      var today = new Date();
      var test = new Date(dateCell);

      // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
      if(test < today){

        var rangeToMove = Sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, Sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
        PastSheet.getRange(PastSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, Sheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(rangeToMove);
        Sheet.deleteRow(i);

      }
    }
  }}

  // Check is a valid date
function isValidDate(value) {
  var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
  return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());
}
```

The expected result would be for all historic rows in Area 2,3 & 4 to move to move to the single historic tab.

My spreadsheet with script is available on the following link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WiZWok4onddTErdAxlWmU82KRSGfVJr5wi1p-rlbY5E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The way you defined `SHEET_NAME`, it will always be "Area 1". You can test this.

```
function test() {
  SHEET_NAME = "Area1" || "Area2" || "Area3"||"Area4";
  Logger.log(SHEET_NAME);
}
```

Instead, `SHEET_NAME` should be an array, and then you need to loop through that array. Below I've included a sample for how to define that array and get the sheets.

```
function loopThroughSpecificSheets() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetNames = ["Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4"];
  for (var j in sheetNames) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[j]);
    // Do other stuff
  }
}
```

Assuming that the rest of your code works correctly (I haven't analyzed it), your modified script would look like this:

```
function HistoricDates() {
  // Initialising
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pastSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Historic Sheet");
  var sheetNames = ["Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4"];
  for (var j in sheetNames) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetNames[j]);
    var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

    // Check all values from sheets
    for(var i = sheet.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--) {
      // Check if the value is a valid date
      var dateCell = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();  //Dates in column 1
      if(isValidDate(dateCell)){
        var today = new Date();
        var test = new Date(dateCell);

        // If the value is a valid date and is a past date, we remove it from the sheet to paste on the other sheet
        if(test < today) {
          var rangeToMove = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
          pastSheet.getRange(pastSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setValues(rangeToMove);
          sheet.deleteRow(i);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Check is a valid date
function isValidDate(value) {
  var dateWrapper = new Date(value);
  return !isNaN(dateWrapper.getDate());
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much Diego, I just had to change the line

`for (var j in specificSheets) {`

to

`for (var j in sheetNames) {`

and the script worked as desired

Comment: @Gerard Thanks for catching that. I changed the names for clarity after testing, but forgot that spot. If the answer resolved your issue, please consider accepting it.